# How can i change the value of a passed object from activity one at activity two (android)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a basic app at android studio.
Simply i have two activity page and three class.

Class 1  MainActivity.java its belong activity 1

Class 2  MarketActivity.java its belong activity 2

Class 3  CharacterAction.java in this class we have character features

On activity 1 we have 3 button

[image: Activity 1]

Button 1 purpose is attack when you clicked the button 1 character will gain 2 attack power.Our purpose is when you bought item on market activity while character attacked it will gain 2+2 attack power.

At CharacterAction.java class we have these :

```
private int kilo;            // Weight
private int hareketSayisi;   //Energy
public int saldiriGucu;      //Attack power
public int saldiriBonus = 2; // it specifies how much attack power you will gain in one attack.

public int getKilo() {  return kilo;  }

public int getHareketSayisi() { return hareketSayisi;  }

public int getSaldiriGucu() { return saldiriGucu;  }

public String savas() {
    if (hareketSayisi > 0) {    // if energy > 0
        hareketSayisi--;        // energy - 1
        saldiriGucu = saldiriGucu + saldiriBonus;    // attackpower = attackpower + attackbonus it will add to attack power + 2
        kilo--;     //weight - 1
            return "karakter savasti";     //return character attacked
    } else {
            return "Yeterli hareket yok";     // there is no energy left
    }
}
```

and MainActivity.java :

```
characterAction.setKilo(10);            // set the weight 10

characterAction.setSaldiriGucu(0);      // set the attack power 0

characterAction.setHareketSayisi(10);   // set the energy 10
```

I passed these objects from MaintActivity.java to MarketActivity.Java :

```
characterAction = (CharacterAction) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("CharacterAction");
```

There is no problem here.

Let's see activity 2 (Market place)

[image: Activity 2]  It says if you buy these sword your attack power gain will increase 2x at your every every attack.

And my question is starting :

I got onClick() method on MarketActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == btnSatinAl1.getId()) {
        tvSuccesful.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (characterAction.saldiriGucu > 10) {    // if attackpower > 10
            characterAction.saldiriBonus = (characterAction.saldiriBonus * 2);    // attack power bonus * 2
            tvSuccesful.setText("Satın alım başarılı");    // Succesful
                    btnSatinAl1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        } else {
            tvSuccesful.setText("Yetersiz saldiri gücü");    // Not enough attack power.
        }
    }
}
```

On these onClick() method it needs to add +2 attack bonus while succesfully bought the sword.But it wont.On the MarketActivity.java it says Succesfully Bought but when i turn Activity 1 and trying to attack its still giving +2 attack power for each attack.

How can i increase these ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: When you pass the object to second activity, it makes a copy there and edits that instance. So, when you return to your first activity, you are accessing the instance that was created in the first activity which is not the same as your second activity. If you want to manipulate data across multiple activities, use database or shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

There are few possible ways that you can resolve this, I would start the MarketActivity with *

```
startActivityForResult()
```

**Way 1:**

Use cache, in MarketActivity update object and save updated in cache, next in first Activity you should update your object from cache for example wtih:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when (requestCode to resultCode) {
            Navigator.XXX_REQUEST_CODE to Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                refreshDataFromCache()
            }
        }
    }
```

**Way 2:**

If you don't want to use cache, pass updated object in result intent's data and then update object and next UI:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when (requestCode to resultCode) {
            Navigator.XXX_REQUEST_CODE to Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                data?.let {
                    val xxx = Parcels.unwrap<XXX>(data.getParcelableExtra(xActivity.DATA_TAG))
                    item = Parcels.unwrap<XXX>(data.getParcelableExtra(xActivity.DATA_TAG))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> Parcels.unwrap is from https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with changing the public int saldiriBonus = 2; // attack bonus
to public static int saldiriBonus = 2;
All i do this.
Changing the method to static *.*.